# Azure Cosmos DB: TypeError: Cannot read property 'electionId' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB with mongodb backend. I'm keep getting this error.

```
Exception has occurred: Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'electionId' of undefined
at ReplSetState.update (c:\dev\3dshoppers.backend\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset_state.js:371:70)
at Server._handleEvent (c:\dev\3dshoppers.backend\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:421:45)
at Server.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
at c:\dev\3dshoppers.backend\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:297:14
at c:\dev\3dshoppers.backend\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:457:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I'm using mongodb@2.2.19. If I update the npm package to the latest version, I get different error ('MongoError: pool destroyed'). I think there is some problem with Cosmos DB......

This is happening on this line in replset_state.js.

```
var currentElectionId = self.set[self.primary.name.toLowerCase()].electionId;
```

EDIT: I was able to reproduce the bug with two files below.

server.js

```
// packages
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// express app
const app = express();
// mongodb
const mongoConnectionString = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING;
const mongoOptions =
{
    connectTimeoutMS: 0
}

var mongoDB;
var myCollection;

MongoClient.connect(mongoConnectionString, (err, db) => {

    if (err) throw err;

    mongoDB = db.db('testdb');

    mongoDB.collection('cars', (err, collection) => {            
            if (err) throw err;            
            myCollection = collection;
        });

        http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "mongodb-debug",
    "description": "mongodb debugging",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": "me",
    "engines": {
        "node": "6.9.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.15.2",
        "mongodb": "2.2.19"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "test": "mocha"
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more code around this. Clearly `self.set[self.primary.name.toLowerCase()]` evaluates to `undefined` and hence the error. As to why?, then we would need to see more of what you are doing that causes this. Also see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help section, as we likely don't need to see your entire program. Just the minimal required to replicate the problem.

Comment: And more to the point, this is **not** about debugging the libraries. Those work perfectly for lots and lots of people. Something is at fault on your end. Bad credentials, Bad connection string, etc etc

Comment: my connection string ends with ?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb

Comment: Much more information than that. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44148718/edit) your question and include  everything relevent to reproduce. Here is the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link again. Please take the time to read it.

Comment: included reproducible example..

Comment: It's better. Now as an excercise in debugging can you try and reproduce on your local machine ( i.e connect to a local instance ) then maybe try another remote provider ( there are several to find with a quick web search ) and try and set up and connect a database there. That will at least narrow down whether it's about your setup of the configuration of the remote service. You do that and can tell us 1. tested local and working 2. tested with remote service, "here take a look at this connection string to try yourself". Then it really narrows things down. Yes?

Comment: @NeilLunn - I wouldn't jump immediately to "it's something at fault on your end." Cosmos DB's MongoDB API is *not* the same as MongoDB, and the OP could have run into a difference (hard to tell with the dearth of code shown, or with lack of shared Cosmos DB config info). 2nd: it appears you're suggesting they share their connection string for others to try out. I don't think that's wise guidance.

Comment: @DavidMakogon You are not reading carefully and jumping to conclusions yourself. 1. The only original content of the Post was pointing to a stack trace in the library code, so that's what they were told not to debug. Of course connections etc can also be an issue. 2. I never asked for "production account" details, and actually specifically mention setting up with another provider specifically for the purpose of test. So what I think is good guidance, is running someone through the motions of things they should be doing to narrow it down. if you think you have an answer then give one to the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the issue by removing the `&replicaSet=globaldb` from the connection string if you are not using a replica set and only have a single Cosmos DB instance.

The similar issue could be found here: [MongoError: Pool Destroyed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6f76f08-903e-49a1-8e6b-3fcd17e0d981/mongodbnode-mongoerror-pool-destroyed?forum=AzureDocumentDB).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error:

```
Thu May 25 2017 05:17:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'electionId' of undefined
    at ReplSetState.update (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset_state.js:353:70)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:393:45)
    at Server.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:280:14
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:455:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'electionId' of undefined
    at ReplSetState.update (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset_state.js:353:70)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:393:45)
    at Server.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:280:14
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:455:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

also using cosmos-db with my node-js application.
The connection works fine because all my collection where created

hier is the package.json and the complete project

https://github.com/aumanjoa/chronas-community/blob/master/package.json#L48
https://github.com/aumanjoa/chronas-community/